# Can't size <DIV> height correctly on mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

First, I'm new to mobile development, so apologies in advance for what might be a simple question.  But I've researched this for a couple of days and just can't seem to get it to work.

I can't get a particular DIV to render at the appropriate height when I switch to a mobile view.  All the other divs work fine in both desktop and mobile.  The div in question looks fine in the desktop view but not in mobile.

Here's a link to the page:  http://echoflyfishing.com/2016

The div in question is the "DOUBLE HAND".  I want it the same height as the "SINGLE HAND" above it.  No matter what I do, I can't get it to size correctly.  I know there's a simple solution but I've tried everything I can think of in terms of height and am stumped.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
                <div class="sh_container_m">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sh_container_table_m">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 3.5vw;padding-top: 2vw; padding-bottom: 2vw;"><p>Single Hand</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="sh_images_container_m">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>This is where the single hand image carousel will be</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class="dh_container_m">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="dh_container_table_m">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size: 3.5vw;"><p>Double Hand</p></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div class="dh_images_container_m">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>This is where the double hand image carousel will be</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.dh_container_m
{
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;

}

.dh_container_table_m
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100vw;
    border: none;
    background-color: #fbaa27 !important;   
}
```

Comment: Your are setting a height of `20vw` on `.sh_images_container_m td` in your CSS file (line 263)

Comment: you are setting widths is percentage and vw on siblings be consistent

Comment: Holy crap, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean for your dh_images_container_m div to be nested inside the sh_images_container_m div? It is going to take on it's "parents" properties which may also be contributing to some of your sizing issues.

On a side note, you have your links to the css files in the header as type="text". They should be type="css/text".

Comment: I didn't mean for that but it seems to be the only way I can get the divs to stack appropriately.  I've tried not nesting them but the stacking becomes a mess.  Any advice would be welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use px not vw because it's percentage and define the width of both divs as you want simple one more suggestion is use bootstrap css framework it's better for you you can make responsive site easily with the help of it.

Comment: I want the site to size dynamically based on width.  I guess I assume that using specific pixel widths will mean that I have to set those at each breakpoint, which seems cumbersome and, more importantly, implies that the DIVs won't shrink and stretch dynamically but will change only upon hitting a breakpoint, right?  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: i saw your site many of things you need to change on it. First of all your site html not have any main container/wrapper after body. Inside it you have put all site html include header and footer and also define container width. If you want 100% width it's up to you because right now i'm seeing scroll-bar on bottom this not good. This is responsive site so it should be work fine all screen. Second thing it's better for you use "20%" except "20vw" better to understand, yes! you are right you have to use div width percentage so then it will be re-sized according to screen width.

Comment: Width percentage or pixel it's doesn't meter actually it's depend on your requirements because you can change width in media quires so it's doesn't meter. Your template fluid so that is why you need percentage for main containers of divs in some divs you have to use width in pixel for example orange box on slide this box no need to resize i think and font size also. Maybe this information will be helpful for you. One more thing use (getbootstrap.com) css framwork. It is very easy. You can make template in few hours that is why i'm suggestion you this one.